# How can I use the word boundary regex with Danish literals?

Tags: regex

I am danish and I need to convert the following Regex so it supports danish literals like ÆØÅ.

```
\b(\w{1,4}|\w{8,})\b
```

When I use this it doesn't work if I have other characters than US-ascii letters.

How can I transform it so it works with universal litterals

For the record I am using gksinner's regex

Comment: Specify the language. Unicode support - or lack of, and quirks with - is very implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use \w, use hex literals for the danish letters directly.